# Formatting issue for View

Tags: sharepoint-online, json, json-formatting, view-formatting

UPDATE:::

Sorry everyone I have been clearer.  This is supposed to be for the "format my view" feature in the Sharepoint Online custom list.  I'm trying to make the entire row change color based on the "assigned?" column. I know i can do it for the column only but I want the whole row to highlight.  When I try several guides, nothing happens.

This is one of the guides that I used but it didn't change the view.
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/formatting-list-views-f737fb8b-afb7-45b9-b9b5-4505d4427dd1

[image]

I'm sure that this code is written correctly but it's not doing anything. A coworker of mine is helping me with the JSON but neither of us can figure out why it isn't working on Sharepoint Online.

[image]

Here is the code.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "@Assigned?",
    "style":
    {
        "color": "#fff",
        "padding-left": "14px",
        "background-color":
        {
            "operator": "?",
            "operands": [
            {
                "operator": "==",
                "operands": ["@Assigned?", "Not Released Yet"]
            }, "#2ECC71",
            {
                "operator": "?",
                "operands": [
                {
                    "operator": "==",
                    "operands": ["@Assigned?", "Needs Reassignment"]
                }, "#E74C3C",
                {
                    "operator": "?",
                    "operands": [
                    {
                        "operator": "==",
                        "operands": ["@Assigned?", "Needs Assignment"]
                    }, "#F1C40F",
                    {
                        "operator": "?",
                        "operands": [
                        {
                            "operator": "==",
                            "operands": ["@Assigned?", "Assigned"]
                        }, "#FFFFF", ""]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared what this is supposed to do. You may be sure it is correct, but without knowing what you are trying to do it is hard to know what to suggest.

Comment: Looks like the reference of column is wrong in your JSON. As per MS documentations it must be specified in `"[$Title]"` format, instead of `"@Assigned?"`. Refer to the multi-line JSON example here https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-list-formatting/blob/master/view-samples/multi-line-view/multiline-view.json

Comment: What is the internal of your `@Assigned?` column? Refer [Checking internal of column in SharePoint](https://plumsail.com/docs/help-desk-o365/v1.x/How%20To/Find%20the%20internal%20name%20of%20SharePoint%20column.html).

Answer (score 1):

What does "@Assigned?" represent in your code? Is it the name of current column? If so, pleace use "@currentField" instead of "@Assigned?".

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "style":
    {
        "color": "#fff",
        "padding-left": "14px",
        "background-color":
        {
            "operator": "?",
            "operands": [
            {
                "operator": "==",
                "operands": ["@currentField", "Not Released Yet"]
            }, "#2ECC71",
            {
                "operator": "?",
                "operands": [
                {
                    "operator": "==",
                    "operands": ["@currentField", "Needs Reassignment"]
                }, "#E74C3C",
                {
                    "operator": "?",
                    "operands": [
                    {
                        "operator": "==",
                        "operands": ["@currentField", "Needs Assignment"]
                    }, "#F1C40F",
                    {
                        "operator": "?",
                        "operands": [
                        {
                            "operator": "==",
                            "operands": ["@currentField", "Assigned"]
                        }, "#FFFFF", ""]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Test result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the impression that you have misled, there is two errors appearing here:

The first is `"txtContent": "@Assigned?"` should be `"txtContent": "@currentField"`

The second you are trying to format a row in a column formatting section ? even if you correct the first error it will format only the column you are working on, but for the whole row please check this article: 
https://aslamsumayya.wordpress.com/2015/04/10/changing-colors-in-sharepoint-list-rows-conditional-formatting-in-sharepoint-2013online/

I hope this will enlighten you something,
Best wishes for you.

Comment: I was using this Microsoft article

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/formatting-list-views-f737fb8b-afb7-45b9-b9b5-4505d4427dd1